# installation failure when installing jcl-2.4.1.4571 for delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, jedi, jedi-code-library

when installing  jcl-2.4.1.4571 for delphi 7 , I ran across following failure message:

File not found: 'Docktoolform.dcu'

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: official support forum: http://newsportal.delphi-jedi.org/thread_frameset.php?group=jedi.jcl

Comment: when installing clear the checkbox of IDE Experts / StackTrace

Comment: consider http://www.borlandtalk.com/dockable-forms-in-the-ide-vt59928.html and http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=73014

Comment: So, did you solve the problem? if yes - then publish the essence, help future readers! http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed JEDI/JCL on several machines over the years, in WinXP/Delphi 5 and D2007, and now on 3 different machines that have Windows 7 Ultimate and DXE and DXE5.  I remember having some problems with the install years ago, and on one of the 3 Win 7 boxes I had trouble installing it in DXE.  The problems were with compiling the installer such the install.bat aborted early, reporting F1026 on Forms.dcu.

I could not find anything different about this one Win7/DXE box, so none of the usual recommended solutions helped at all.

What solved the problem for me was opening a command window in the folder containing install.bat and simply running the following command for DXE:

install d15

That ran the process of installing JCL and then I repeated the same command in the folder for JVCL.

I only use DXE5 for a deployment to OSX that doesn't use JEDI, so I don't yet know if using the following command will work for DXE5:

install d19

Oh, don't forget to uncheck the boxes for versions of Delphi you don't want to install.  These options are on separate tab-pages for each version of Delphi.